# POST request it being turned into GET request when using http instead of https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ssl, nginx

After adding SSL I have noticed a strange behaviour: All API POST requests using HTTP protocol in the address are being turned into GET requests and this is why I am getting `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v2/users")` error.

My nginx.conf:

```
upstream unicorn_staging.xxxxx.com {
 server unix:/srv/www/xxxxx/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name staging.xxxxx.com xxxxx dublin;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.xxxxx.com.access.log;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

  root /srv/www/xxxxx/current/public/;


  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_staging.xxxxx.com;
      break;
    }
  }

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /srv/www/xxxxx/current/public/;
  }
}

server {
  listen   443;
  server_name staging.xxxxx.com xxxxx dublin;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/staging.xxxxx.com-ssl.access.log;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/staging.xxxxx.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/staging.xxxxx.com.key;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

  root /srv/www/xxxxx/current/public/;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_staging.xxxxx.com;
      break;
    }
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /srv/www/xxxxx/current/public/;
  }
}
```

I am using Ruby on Rails, Nginx and unicorn. I have set force_ssl to true in rails so it automatically redirects all the requests to https.
Access log when using https:

`[01/Apr/2016:08:58:28 +0000] "GET /api/v2/users HTTP/1.1" 404 15384 "-" "XxxxStaging/28 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0"`

Access log when using http:

`[01/Apr/2016:09:00:08 +0000] "POST /api/v2/users HTTP/1.1" 201 1620 "-" "curl/7.43.0"`